# SVG element not clickable on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, svg

This is the code below to reproduce

```
<svg focused="true" width="338.35" height="338.35" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 1200 1600" style="overflow:visible;">

   <g onclick="alert(2)" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0,375.7469534186119,500.9959378914826)">  
    <rect width="600" height="800" fill="red"></rect>
  </g>

  <g onclick="alert(1)" transform="translate(1537.23915382511058,0) rotate(0,375.7469534186119,500.9959378914826)">

    <rect width="600" height="800"></rect>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fb6swzba/

When a box clicked, it alerts a number. As you see, the red box works in both browsers. On chrome, both red and black box works. But on Safari red box works, but black box is not reactive at all.

When **rect** is out of the width defined in SVG, it's visible on the browser as style **overflow:visible** does that. But it's not clickable on safari browsers however the same example works in Chrome.

Comment: See if it's a known webkit bug and if not report it

Comment: I've reported to Apple, let's see. I think something can be done from our end to avoid this issue.